# regarding the access of funds during an ongoing token presale of my token

Tags: tokens, airdrop, presale

we are planning a token presale for our crypto token with all the specific requirements but we are unclear about the control of funds raised while an presale is still live. can anyone please clarify this thing that can we as the owner of the token and its issuance, withdraw funds which are already raised in order to pay for the milestones while the presale is still in live phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the contract you use for the presale.

If the contract has functionality for you to withdraw funds at some point, then you can do it. If it doesn't have such functionality, you obviously can't do it.

Usually the assets live in the contract and its code has limited functionality to allow the withdrawal of these assets. Usually only certain address can withdraw the funds at certain time or after certain conditions have been met.

Comment: so if it has a function which enables the owner to withdraw the funds at any given point of time to utilize it for further development, can it be done?

Comment: I think you already answered yourself. If it has such a function, then the owner can use it.

Comment: thank you for your kind response.